# Code using OpenCV not drawing trajectory of object after tracking

Tags: python, opencv

For testing purposes I'm a vid of a ball bouncing. The video plays, but no trajectory is being drawn. Truth be told I cant even be sure the object is being tracked or not. I've tried adjusting colour ranges but that seems to not change anything. I've checked with others and  they seem to suggest adjusting the colour threshhold and checking if the contours are being detected correctly using the mask. Not particularly sure how t do that last one, but I'm hoping the issue is more simple. Any help is appreciated.

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import imutils
import time
import os

# Construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", default="test_vid_1.mp4", help="path to the video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# Get the path to the video file
video_path = args["video"]

# Check if the video file exists
if not os.path.exists(video_path):
    print(f"Error: The video file '{video_path}' does not exist.")
    exit()

# Initialize the video stream
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Check if the video stream is opened successfully
if not vs.isOpened():
    print(f"Error: Failed to open video file '{video_path}'.")
    exit()

# Initialize the lower and upper boundaries of the object in HSV color space
# (Here, it's set for a green object, you may need to adjust these values for your object)
lower_color = (29, 86, 6)
upper_color = (64, 255, 255)

# Initialize the deque to store the tracked points
pts = deque(maxlen=64)

# Loop over frames from the video stream
while True:
    # Read the next frame from the video stream
    ret, frame = vs.read()

    # If we did not grab a frame, then we have reached the end of the video
    if not ret:
        break

    # Resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV color space
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Construct a mask for the object, then perform a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small blobs left in the mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

    # Find contours in the mask and initialize the current (x, y) center of the object
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    center = None

    # If at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # Find the largest contour in the mask, then use it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

        print(f"Center: {center}, Radius: {radius}")

        # Only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if radius > 10:
            # Draw the circle and centroid on the frame, then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius), (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # Update the points queue
    pts.appendleft(center)

    # Loop over the set of tracked points
    for i in range(1, len(pts)):
        # If either of the tracked points are None, ignore them
        if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
            continue

        # Otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and draw the connecting lines
        thickness = int(np.sqrt(64 / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
        cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)

    # Show the frame to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # If the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# Release the video stream
vs.release()

# Close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What is colour of ball?